# Dynamically change text colour to a SPECIFIC colour depending on background

Tags: css, animation, background, mix-blend-mode

I've got a list of menu items, and to indicate the "active" item, it gets a certain background colour. When the active item changes to another, this background slides to the new item with an animation.

Inactive menu items are coloured black, active menu items are coloured white, and the background is coloured blue (for simplicity - the exact colours are obviously irrelevant). **The active colour should only be applied to the part of the text that has the indicatory background behind it.**

I know I can use `mix-blend-mode: difference` in case the text starts off being the same colour as the moving background. In my case, **the text has a different colour than the background when the item is inactive**.

How can I achieve this effect using CSS?

For reference, the implementation with `mix-blend-mode: difference` is as follows:

```js
const slider = document.querySelector('.tab-slider');

document.querySelectorAll('.tabs a').forEach(a => {
  a.onclick = () => {
    document.querySelector('.active').classList.remove('active');
    
    const li = a.parentElement;
    
    li.classList.add('active');
    
    slider.style.left = li.offsetLeft + "px";
    slider.style.width = li.offsetWidth + "px";
  };
});

// init
const li = document.querySelector(".active");
slider.style.left = li.offsetLeft + "px";
slider.style.width = li.offsetWidth + "px";
slider.style.height = li.offsetHeight + "px";
```

```css
html {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.tabs ul {
  display: flex;
  list-style-type: none;
}

.tabs li {
  padding-block: 2px;
  padding-inline: 5px;
}

.tabs a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: blueviolet;
  mix-blend-mode: difference;
}

.tab-slider {
  position: absolute;
  background: blueviolet;
  z-index: -1;
  transition: all 1000ms;
}
```

```html
<nav class="tabs">
  <div class="tab-slider"></div>

  <ul>
    <li class="active"><a href="#">about</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">summary</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">refs</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">log</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">tree</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">commit</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">diff</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">stats</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: What colors do you want? As you know from your example code, it isn’t actually irrelevant - there may be a mix-blend answer or there may not.

Comment: @AHaworth I'd like the colours to be customisable, so I'm looking for a solution that works with any three colours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to have complete control of the three colors is to make the overlay a copy of the whole list, with pointer events off and a clip-path to show only that part that is active, with a transition (as now) between the start and end clip-paths.

```html
<style>
  html {
    font-family: sans-serif;
  }
  
  * {
    margin: 0;
  }
  
  .tabs {
    position: relative;
  }
  
  .tabs ul {
    display: flex;
    list-style-type: none;
  }
  
  .tabs li {
    padding-block: 2px;
    padding-inline: 5px;
  }
  
  .tabs a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: blueviolet;
  }
  
  .tabs .tab-slider {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: red;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    transition: all 1000ms;
    clip-path: polygon(var(--left) 0, var(--right) 0, var(--right) 100%, var(--left) 100%);
  }
  
  .tabs .tab-slider a {
    color: yellow;
    pointer-events: none;
  }
</style>
<nav class="tabs">
  <ul class="tab-slider">
    <li><a href="#">about</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">summary</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">refs</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">log</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">tree</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">commit</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">diff</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">stats</a></li>
  </ul>

  <ul class="main">
    <li><a href="#" class="active">about</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">summary</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">refs</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">log</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">tree</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">commit</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">diff</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">stats</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>

<script>
  const slider = document.querySelector('.tab-slider');

  document.querySelectorAll('.tabs ul.main a').forEach(a => {
    a.onclick = () => {
      document.querySelector('.active').classList.remove('active');

      const li = a.parentElement;

      li.classList.add('active');

      //slider.style.left = li.offsetLeft + "px";
      //slider.style.width = li.offsetWidth + "px";
      slider.style.setProperty('--left', li.offsetLeft + "px");
      slider.style.setProperty('--right', li.offsetLeft + li.offsetWidth + "px");
    };
  });

  // init
  const li = document.querySelector(".active");
  slider.style.setProperty('--left', li.offsetLeft + "px");
  slider.style.setProperty('--right', li.offsetLeft + li.offsetWidth + "px");
</script>
```